# Converting a string into BigInteger

Tags: c#, string, parsing, type-conversion, biginteger

I have the following code that creates a very big number (`BigInteger`) which is converted then into a `string`.

```
// It's a console application.
BigInteger bi = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < 1234; i++)
{
   bi *= 2;
}
string myBigIntegerNumber = bi.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(myBigIntegerNumber);
```

I know that for converting to `int` we can use `Convert.ToInt32` and converting to `long` we use `Convert.ToInt64`, but what's about converting to `BigInteger`?

How can I convert a `string` (that represents a very very long number) to `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`BigInteger.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285.aspx) method.

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style to
>   its BigInteger equivalent.

```
BigInteger bi = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < 1234; i++)
{
    bi *= 2;
}

var myBigIntegerNumber = bi.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Parse(myBigIntegerNumber));
```

Also you can check [`BigInteger.TryParse(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268301.aspx)) method with your conversation is successful or not.

> Tries to convert the string representation of a number to its
>   BigInteger equivalent, and returns a value that indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which is faster compared to `BigInteger.Parse()`

```
public static BigInteger ToBigInteger(string value)
{
    BigInteger result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        result = result * 10 + (value[i] - '0');
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: With minor problems like it doesn't handle negative numbers.